# TypeScript Global variables not changed in Observable subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use rxJS to handle responses from an http request in angular2

this is the code:

```
isUserConfirmed(): boolean {
    let result: boolean = false;
    this.authService.isUserConfirmed().subscribe(
      retrievedData => {
        //if no errors from the server
        if (retrievedData.success) {
          //if the confirmed flag is true
          if (retrievedData.payload){
            result = true;
            console.log("i"+result);
          } else {
            result = false;

          }
        } else {
          this.showError(retrievedData.message);
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
      console.log("o"+result);
      return result;
  },

showError(error) {
  //...
}
```

**EDIT**

When I run this, I get this output:

`ofalse`
`itrue`

This means that the result value is set to true inside suscribe method, but  that does not change returned result value.
How can I manage to return the value set from inside the subscribe block?

Answer (score 1):

Its because your console statement outside the subscribe block will execute first. So your first console.log() will display false. Following your console.log() inside the subscribe block will be executed second. So it will result to true if success.

If Observable returns true, result should be :

```
false
true
```

You can return value in this way

```
isUserConfirmed(): boolean {
    let result: boolean = false;
    return this.authService.isUserConfirmed().subscribe(
      retrievedData => {
        //if no errors from the server
        if (retrievedData.success) {
          //if the confirmed flag is true
          if (retrievedData.payload){
            result = true;
            console.log("i"+result);
          }
        } else {
          this.showError(retrievedData.message);
        }
        return result
      },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: you are right about the log order, so how can i manage to return the result value from the suscribe block ?

Comment: I have added the code, look at the return statements.                               1. return this.authService.isUserConfirmed().subscribe()                                2. return result                                                                                         This might solve your problem